# How to find a form in a URL code and send it with submit()

Tags: python, selenium

I have a URL with different items. Every item has an associated button_item and when this button_item is clicked on, a pop-up window appears with a marked default option and a submit button. This pop-up window is apparently the same for all items in the source window but actually it isn't because the server knows which button_item you clicked on (we know this).
How can I implement in python/selenium the action of this submit button without having to click on it, not even opening the corresponding popup window?

I am guessing I would have to find in the HTLM code the form or information corresponding to that popup window and then apply a submit() method. My idea was to find the form through the ID of the particular item which is a string specific for every item and I guess it's the element used by the server to know which item you cliked on exactly.

Something like:

driver.find_element_by_???("itemID").submit()

I don't know which method to use after "driver." for finding the right form and submitting it.

Thanks

Comment: It's not HTML.  You would have to find the Javascript code that brings the popup and figure out what the button press does.  It probably does not submit a form, unless you see the screen repaint.  If the popup just goes away, then it's just updating Javascript data within the page.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to do it but at least I know where to search

Comment: I forgot one question Tim, following you indications, is my idea viable with python-selenium?

Comment: Well, that's an item for you to research.  It's either you tracing through the Javascript figuring out how they built the dialog and submitting a POST request to match, or using selenium to scrape the screen after the dialog is visible.  Neither one is very much fun.  It would be better if your target had a well-defined API.